# install matlab only recognizes python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, ubuntu-18.04

I want to have matlab python3.6 integration on my ubuntu 18.04. I installed the matlab engine with no problem. And I found the matlab module at /usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/engines/python

When I run python setup.py install, it keeps write files out to

```
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matlab/engine/_arch.txt -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matlab/engine
```

But I need this to work with python3.6. Even when I run this in my conda env running python3.6, it still only recognizes python2.7. Anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: Did you set the intended version and directory using the `pyenv` command?

Comment: why pyenv? I use conda env.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. This problem is fixed once I managed to install python3.6 in my ubuntu.